# what is the current stage of ubuntu tablet , is it viable to use with a android note 10.1?

Tags: android, tablet

I want to practise on ubuntu tablet os with my note 10.1. Is it possible to load it to my tabler as keepjng the android alive as backup.? Or is tblet os is not ready yet to load it into machine? what is the present progress?

Answer (score 0):

Make it a dual boot, or load ubuntu through android itself and test it out for a week. Remember android is linux OS, ubuntu can function on almost all android devices i'm sure, (I've even begun to question on ubuntu running on an android emulator console even.)